# How to modify/edit manifest file or application icon after installation by using other application or run-time by getting response from api

Tags: java, android, apk, android-manifest, android-shell

I'm curious about to know that how to add other flags to activity and broadcast receiver by editing manifest file of application. Change application's launcher icon & short-cut icon.

And generate new apk to install with this changes or done this changes without any re-installation of application.

This could be done by application itself, by getting notified from server like some of google applications changes their app icon run-time without any re-installation
Or just other application that does this on installed application. Like this one :-> [**apkpermremover**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.apkpermremover)

Please help me to learn this. 
All answers are appreciated. Thank you.

Does anyone can help me out ?!!

Comment: You cannot change the installed apk.  You could generate a new one, using the same procedures as various reverse engineering tools and sdk components, but porting them is well beyond the scope of an SO question.  Spend time understanding what exists first.

Comment: So I have to create new updated build on every change. Ok, that's no problem. Now how to retrieve and view installed application's files like manifest and res folders and generate new apk build programmatically like ** apk perm remover ** is working.

In what I have to search for answer ?

Comment: Many of the reverse engineering tools are open source; most utilize Android SDK components which are themselves open source.  If you want to do this kind of project, you are going to have to be willing to take time to do your own research!